# Huffman's Data compression filltable and invert code problems

Tags: c++, compression, huffman-code

I just began learning about Huffman's Data compression algorithm and I need help on the following function > filltable() and invertcode()

I don't understand why a codetable array is needed.

```
while (n>0){
   copy = copy * 10 + n %10;
   n /= 10;
}
```

Please help me understand what is going on for this part of the function and why if n is larger than 0 it is divided by ten because it is alway going to be greater than 0 no matter how many times you divided it.

Link for code: http://www.programminglogic.com/implementing-huffman-coding-in-c/

```
void fillTable(int codeTable[], Node *tree, int Code){

    if (tree->letter<27)
        codeTable[(int)tree->letter] = Code;
    else{
        fillTable(codeTable, tree->left, Code*10+1);
        fillTable(codeTable, tree->right, Code*10+2);
    }

    return;
}
void invertCodes(int codeTable[],int codeTable2[]){
    int i, n, copy;

    for (i=0;i<27;i++){
        n = codeTable[i];
        copy = 0;
        while (n>0){
            copy = copy * 10 + n %10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        codeTable2[i]=copy;
}
```

** edit **

To make this question more clear I don't need an explanation on huffman encoding and decoding but I need a explanation on how these two functions work and why codetables are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is an int. Therefore, it will reduce to 0 over time. If n starts at 302 at the first iteration, it will be reduced to 30 after the first `n /= 10;`. At the end of the second iteration of the while loop, it will be reduced to 3. at the end of the fourth iteration, it will equal 0 ( int 4 / int 10 = int 0 ).

It is integer math. No decimal bits to extend to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I made a minor update to the example program to include an end of data code. The original example code may append an extra letter to the end of the original data when decompressing. Also there's a lot of stuff "hard coded" in this code, such as the number of codes, which was 27, and which I changed to 28 to include the end of data code that I added, and also the output file names which I changed to "compress.bin" (if compressing) or "output.txt" (if decompressing). It's not an optimal implementation, but it's ok to use as a learning example. It would help if you follow the code with a source level debugger.

http://rcgldr.net/misc/huffmanx.zip

A more realistic Huffman program would use tables to do the encode and decode. The encode table is indexed with the input code, and each table entry contains two values, the number of bits in the code, and the code itself. The decode table is indexed with a code composed of the minimum number of bits from the input stream required to determine the code (it's at least 9 bits, but may need to be 10 bits), and each entry in that table contains two values, the actual number of bits, and the character (or end of data) represented by that code. Since the actual number of bits may be less than the number bits used to determine the code, the left over bits will need to be buffered and used before reading data from the compressed file.

One variation of a Huffman like process is to have the length of the code determined by the leading bits of each code, to reduce the size of the decode table.